# Is it true that Indra was a supreme God in Vedic time?

Tags: vedas, shiva, gods, rig-veda, indra

Many Indologists say that Indra is the greatest deity in Rigveda. Is it true that Demi God Indra was greater than Shiva and Vishnu ?

Comment: As per Vedas No God is inferior or superior than other Gods. That's why Indra is praised and invoked during yajna like Rudra and Vishnu. That's why every God would have equal share in Yajna.